# Supplemental read for Rotman's Algebraic Topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

As I'm going through Rotman's "Algebraic Topology", I was interested in knowing of a separate book to help supplement with the Singular Homology covered in Rotman's Text. I searched around and found William Massey's "Singular Homology Theory" and saw it covers alot more singular homology than rotman's text. Would Massey's text work as a supplement for Rotman's text? What other texts would be useful for extra coverage singular homology theory?

I've also noticed that there's very few reviews on Massey's "Singular Homology Theory" Text, So I'm not entirely sure of what people think of the text.

Massey's text covers a form of homology called cubical singular homology and I understand that Simplical singular homology is found to be more useful than cubical singular homology. Should I stick learning simplical singular homology or would be a bonus to understand both theories of homology?

Comment: Massey's book is on cubical singular homology, which has been unfashionable, but is coming back into prominence, some of the reasons for which are set out in this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357717300460 . He and his collaborators developed some fundamental algebraic topology.

Answer (score 7):

I love all Rotman's textbooks, but I feel this one is underrated. It's deep, abstract and precise without divorcing the subject from the geometry, as many "modern" texts sadly do. I consider it the perfect supplement to an algebraic topology course using Allen Hatcher's book. Hatcher's handwaving, annoyingly imprecise approach makes a lot of people's eyes glaze over. While it's focus on geometry is very helpful in understanding the roots of the subject, he's way too loose with definitions and terminology. The 2 books complement each other extraordinarily well.

As for your question, many algebraic topology textbooks cover singular homology in depth. But few cover all the various modern homology theories like Tammo tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology*. I think you'll find it extraordinarily informative and it's written by a master of the subject. But be warned-it's far more abstract then even Rotman. The only pictures in the book are commutative diagrams and homotopy schematics! It's not an easy book by any stretch of the imagination, but if you're really interested in homology theories, it's a must read.